# SQL Server mdf files not changing

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

Here is a SQL Server question.

While data is getting populated or deleted from a data base (ex. NorthwindDB), the corresponding mdf file is not changing at all. But to test this I restarted the SQL Server services and I could see the change in time stamp and size of the mdf file.

Is there any way we can force the data base changes to reflect in the corresponding mdf and ldf files without restarting the SQL Service.

Comment: You might be observing the [write-ahead logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835093(v=sql.110).aspx) used by Sql Server, i.e. the .LDF is written to before the .MDF / .NDF. Why would you need to observe file timestamps on the files?

Comment: I need to copy the mdf and ldf file to some other server,, I need to be sure that the DB transactions are implemented onto the files before I copy them

Comment: AFAIK you'll need to either stop Sql Server, or Detach the Database in question before doing this, otherwise the copied files won't be useable. You'll might want to consider instead using a supported BACKUP, Log Shipping, Mirroring, or Replication approach.

Comment: Windows made a change in behavior starting with Server 2008 IIRC. The directory entries are not updated until the file is closed. This was done for performance reasons, but it breaks your expectation re: how things should work. As far as I know there is no work around and MS does not seem to care.  Here is an <a href="http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it.aspx#pi47623=3">article related to the issue</a> on their customer care site. MS changes links often, it is most complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:
    DBCC SHRINKFILE (Transact-SQL)

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx).

Personally I use this:

```
USE MyDB;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE MyDB;
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDB_log_NAME, 1);          
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE MyDB;
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```